# Issue on Excel number formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I'm trying to type a number eg: `65`, and when i press enter it shows as `0.065`. Even I have tried the basic settings still it shows like this.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the cell format? Almost sounds like a "custom" format. Try changing to General and try again.

Answer (score 0):

*There is no custom formatting that will do this.*

Edit...

You've gotta love life, eh? Just recently someone could not get happiness looking for this format.

And a way to do it occurred to me and even though it cannot help the poster since he says he has changed formatting to the basic formatting, I thought I'd add the format:

```
0.000,
```

This will take 65 and display it as 0.065, as he tells of in his posted question (though formatting to a basic, non-custom format would show the underlying 65, so it's not helpful to him).

That leaves macros and if not a macro, then their "sisters," the Add-Ins.

So, check for any macros and for any you find, scour them to see if the cell you are entering the value into is one they can possible affect. Especially, you know, if you notice the macro formats cell entries...

Keep in mind that macros sometimes call other macros in other spreadsheets. This is done, at least in part, to keep you from seeing "under that hood" or to keep you from tinkering with the more intricate parts of a macro.

Following along that thought, you come to Add-Ins. Do the basic Add-In testing. First is to unselect any you have recently added, then restart Excel and see if the problem occurs. If not, leave them inactivated, and begin inactivating Add-Ins and restarting until you have inactivated all of them.

Be especially interested in any Add-Ins that this spreadsheet writer required you to add in for his spreadsheet to function...

If this does not do the trick, try opening Excel in Safe Mode and see what happens. Yes, you are grasping at straws, but sometimes, one is the source of trouble. Make sure all other Office programs are closed and test the problem. Especially Word and Outlook and especially those if the spreadsheet in question requires one of them or feeds one of them. Macros in them may be the issue. Or Add-Ins. Consider anything at all that might have been associated with getting and using this spreadsheet. Look carefully at the macros for things they might look for elsewhere, especially in some odd spot on your network ("odd" = "not YOUR spot") and definitely especially for any web wandering a macro does.

Also check your Personal worksheet, if you have one, and check for one even if you do not think you have one. It is not unheard of for macros to insert things there. It is also not unheard of for things you have there to interact in odd ways with a normal spreadsheet's macros. Though it would be a stretch for this one, but if you get to this point...

It is also possible that you have a corrupted version of the spreadsheet. If you can get a copy from a time before this occurred first, that would allow some worthwhile contrasts. Is this a shared spreadsheet? If so, do others encounter the same issue? Is the spreadsheet's author around to ask about it?

It is very hard to picture what corruption in your installation of Excel could cause this, but if you reach this point, you could try repairing or reinstalling Excel.

Also, use the Windows Task Manager, under BOTH Apps and Background Processes, to make sure the instance of Excel you are running is the ONLY instance running. Close it. Give things 10-15 seconds, then examine both sections for any sign of Excel. If you find anything, force close it. Naturally, if you have anything else running that might conceivably run a copy of Excel on its own (HARD to imagine, but check), close those programs naturally, then examine again. Force close anything you find at this point. Close the Task Manager, then open it again 10-15 seconds later. Look to see if everything is still clean of Excel-related anything.

Fire up Excel again, then the spreadsheet with the issue. Does it still persist? Close it all down, examine Task Manager. If at this point, anything Excel-related persists, you have a serious issue and it is surely a macro or Add-In. Try shutting down the computer, not just "Restart" shut down, but hold the button in and wait for it to really shut down. Give it 10-15 seconds and start it back up. Interact with it not at all except to fire up Excel when possible and open the spreadsheet. Don't start anything else. If the problem persists, it's a macro or Add-In, either acting directly or calling code from another spreadsheet or loading it from a text file to exist only when the spreadsheet is run. You'll have to go to the author if you did all this and still can't see the issue.

The effect you describe, by the way, is one quite a few would love to see available in custom formatting. But it just isn't, hence the emphasis on macros and related kinds of things.